# Implementing the Right GUI Behavior for Form_Find

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-interface

I have a simple application that consists of 2 Forms:
Form_Main, and Form_Find.

**Form_Main** is a big form that has a Grid on it,
**Form_Find** is a small form that has a TextBox and 2 buttons("Previous", "Next") on it.

Form_Find is only shown after the user presses Ctrl-F.

So far everything works good, and I am only left with one problem,
a problem that relates to the GUI.

The problem is this:

Form_Find's **.TopMost** property is set to True.

It works very well when I am in the application,
but when I leave the appication open and switch to another application(e.g. a browser), Form_Main is covered by the new window(e.g. the browser) like it should,
but Form_Find is still floating and shown, covering a part of the other application's window, and disturbing.

I wanted Form_Find to somehow be a child of Form_Main,
so that If I leave/minimize Form_Main, then Form_Find will not continue to appear..
and will only re-appear once I am back to the application - to Form_Main.

To do this, I set Form_Find's **.Parent** property to the instance of Form_Main,
and to make it work, I also needed to write a line before it, which sets Form_Find's **.TopLevel** property to false.
(or else I could not set a Parent to Form_Find)

This actually worked,
and now Form_Find behaves like a child form of Form_Main:
When I switch from my application to another application, both Form_Main and Form_Find are covered by the new appplication's window.

So this problem was indeed solved,
however a new problem has raised due to it, and this new problem is what I am stuck with now.

The new problem is:

Whenever I click the "Next" button in Form_Find,
it causes the Grid control on Form_Main to lose focus.
And when the Grid on Form_Main loses focus, the Grid takes the cell that was in EditMode, out of EditMode.

And this is my problem.

This did not happen before I set Form_Main to be the Parent of Form_Find.
The reason it did not happen, was because when Form_Find is not a child of Form_Main,
then when Form_Find gets focussed, the focussed control in Form_Main never knows about it..
Form_Main may lose the focus to another form, but **the control** inside Form_Main will never know it and will never fire any relevant event about it(only the form will).

So you see,
to make the behavior of Form_Find be well,
I need both of these things:

1) To have Form_Find somehow a child of Form_Main, so when I switch to another window, Form_Find will not continue floating on the screen, covering other applications
2) To have Form_Find not steal focus from the focussed control on Form_Main, when I click the "Next" button on Form_Find. I did have this as long as Form_Find was not a child of Form_Main, but I lost this once I succeeded in making Form_Find be a child of Form_Main.

So my question to you:
What would be the solution to this problem?

Thank you very much

Comment: Try to use `ShowDialog()` instead of `Show()` for `Form_Find` and don't set `TopMost` to `true`.

Comment: This solve the first question, but create a new form that hide nad lock the Main_Form..

Comment: What I not clear is that how your application works. The Find form searched inside a single cell of DataGridView? At the end, the focus can be hold only by a single element, you cannot avoid to lose focus on the Main_Form. What you can do is to store what you need and restore it after search/next method execution.

Comment: I think you can achive faster your goal adding search control on the Main_Form as a little panel with TextBox and Buttons

Comment: **B0Andrew:** As LPs said, If I use .ShowDialog(), then my Main form will be blocked until I close Form_Find.. This is not the behavior I want.. **LPs:** Form_Main has a Grid(specifically C1FlexGrid). When I click the "Next" button in Form_Find, it finds a cell in the Grid that has this substring in it, makes the cell enter EditMode(TextBox appears and enables editing the cell), and selecting in that textbox the substring to be found..

Comment: I see. Then handle `SizeChanged` of the `Form_Main` and set the `Form_Find`'s `WindowState` to appropriate state depending on `Form_Main`'s state.

Comment: **LPs:** Indeed I can add a little panel on Form_Main, which will contain the controls that Form_Find contains, yet I will still have problem #2: **"2) To have Form_Find not steal focus from the focussed control on Form_Main, when I click the "Next" button on Form_Find."** How can I choose problem 2 in this case? (so when clicking the "Next" button in the panel, the grid will not lose focus, so the cell will not go out of EditMode)

Comment: First problem is solved using the owner parameter when you call the Show for Form_Find. IE: _Form_Find ff = new Form_Find(); ff.Show(instance_of_Main_Form);_

Comment: **B0Andrew:** The SizeChanged event will be raised when I minimizeqRestore Form_Find, but I don't think it is raised when I just switch to another application(by covering Form_Main with another application)...

Comment: **Steve:** I solved Problem #1 by using the .Parent property(along with TopLevel=false, so it will succeed). How can .Owner hel in this case? from my test now, .Owner does not achieve the same behavior like .Parent does.. (the .Owner property does not seem to do anything.. at least anything that I notice of..)

Comment: **Steve:** After checking again, it seems that you are right! I am able now to solve problem #2, via setting the .Owner property of Form_Find, to Form_Main! I just needed to set.TopMost back to its original value: false. I will now verify it again that it's OK...

Comment: Try the simple test posted. You get the behavior required, for the second problem, it seems that your problem is in some event handler code that is executed when the cell exits from edit mode right?

Comment: **Steve:** using the .Owner property solves the problem, but once must remember to set .TopMost back to false again.. after doing it it all works perfect - Clicking the "Next" button in Form_Find, does not steal focus from the grid, which means the cell does not go outof EditMode.. Thank you very much! One more question please: If I want to take LPs idea, and completely get rid of Form_Find, and instead use a small Panel on Form_Main, how then will I be able not to steal the focus from the Grid, when clicking the "Next" button in the panel?

Comment: Well, that's a different problem. The controls are on the same form and the behavior of Focus events are very difficult to change to the point that it not worth the effort. Perhaps with the help of some custom control from your component provider? I really don't know.

Comment: OK I understand. Thank you very much Steve. BTW, why didn't you write your solution as an Answer instead of as a Comment? I could then mark it Solved.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To establish the corrent parent/child behavior requested you need to pass the owner form to the child one when you open the child.

This proof of concept could be tested using [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/)
(*I am not involved in any way with them, IMHO it is just the most useful tool that you need)

```
Form f1;
void Main()
{
    f1 = new Form();
    TextBox t1 = new TextBox();
    t1.Location = new Point(0,0);
    TextBox t2 = new TextBox();
    t2.Location = new Point(0,30);
    f1.Controls.AddRange(new Control[] {t1,t2});
    f1.Deactivate += onDeactive;
    f1.Show();

    Form f2 = new Form();
    Button b = new Button();
    b.Click += bClick;
    f2.Controls.Add(b);

    // This line pass the F1 form
    // as owner of F2 establishing the 
    // correct parent/child behavior
    f2.Show(f1);
}

void bClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Clicked");
    f1.ActiveControl.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss");
}
void onDeactive(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Main Deactivated");
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Steve. I will add here that in addition to setting the .Owner property of the smaller window to the bigger(owner) window, it is important to turn the smaller window's .TopMost property to false, if it was true(like in my case). Or else problem will still #1 remain. This was a great help! thank you so much :)

Comment: The TopMost property is set by default to false. In this sample you should not change anything from their default values (TopMost, TopLevel, Owner, Parent are all at their default values)